# Java For Loop help

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

Hi
I need to create a Java SHA1 brute force application and need help with the for loops to create the words to guess. I need to guess passwords between 1 and 6 chars long. So I need a loop that starts with A...Z and then AA....AZ etc So adding letters as it goes along.

I am using a Char array to store the letters from a - z and numbers from 0 - 9. Thats what I am looping through.

This is my loop at the moment:

```
for (int a = 0; a<36; a++){

        guess[5] = letters[a];

         for (int b = 0; b<36; b++){

          guess[4] = letters[b];

             for (int c = 0; c<36; c++){

                    guess[3] = letters[c];

             for (int d = 0; d<36; d++){

                     guess[2] = letters[d];

                    for (int e = 0; e<36; e++){

                        guess[1] = letters[e];

                        for (int f = 0; f<36; f++){

                           guess[0] = letters[f];
```

thanks

Comment: D: Are you serious about the code above?

Comment: i had a mistake as I was messing around with the loop so had inputted the wrong indexs. now fixed.

Comment: I sorted it out with 6 for loops and break statements

Comment: What was your question here, actually?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to use arbitrarily nested loops for a brute force algorithm.  Instead, look at it as counting in an arbitrary radix, represented by different symbols, such as [a-z, A-Z, 0-9, etc.] , but you could represent them as counting from say, 0-64 or whatever in a single digit.  That way you may start with aaa, then eventually end up at aaA, and aa0 and eventually 999 if generating 3 digits.

With the way you're doing it, extending it to more digits would require modifying the code.

Comment: I dont need to do it for more then 6 chars and only lowercase. Also the password needs to be between 1 and 6 so could be a 2 chars password.

Comment: @Nekro - his idea here is to unroll the bottom three loops with a bigger lookup table than your current table which is 36.  You would create a lookup table for the bottom that would contain all of the possible 3 letter/number combinations.  Unrolling the loop may be faster.

Comment: @Nekro, how is your existing loop monstrosity going to generate 1,2,3,4 and 5 character passwords?  Are you going to have six loop monstrosities in series?

Answer (score 0):

Your index into `letters[i]` looks wrong.  Should that be the index for each loop level?  In the first should that not be `letters[a]`?

It looks like that would loop through all of the combos, but you have a few incorrect index values and wow, I bet that would take a long time, LOL.

Comment: yes lol I had the wrong index. corrected it now. yes it will take a while but I found it to be the easiest way to do it. Just need to figure out how to start at one char and then loop through a-z and then add another char and loop again etc

Answer (score 0):

After finally understanding the question (thanks to @cHao), here's my proposal:

```
for (int len = 1; len <= 6; ++len) {
    // generate all words of length 'len'
    int [] index = new int[len + 1];
    while (index[len] == 0) {
        // generate the next guess
        for (int pos = 0; pos < len; ++pos) {
            guess[pos] = letters[index[pos]];
        }
        // increment the index
        for (int pos = 0; pos < len; ++pos) {
            if (index[pos] == letters.length - 1) {
                index[pos] = 0;
                // carry to the next position
            } else {
                ++index[pos];
                break;
            }
        }
        // use guess[0] through guess[len-1] as the next word at this point
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If your alphabet is 26 characters then your words correspond to numbers from 1 through 26^6 - 1. So one approach is:

```
int val = 1 + new java.util.Random().nextInt(308915774); // [0 to 26^6 - 1)
String word = Integer.toString(val, 26).toUpperCase(); // from [0-9,A-P]
word = word.replace('0', 'Q');
// etc for '1', through '9', where '9' -> Z
```

If you want to include 0-9 (36-character alphabet), then this trick isn't going to work because `36^6 - 1 > Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I suggest then that you use `Random.nextInt()` to decide how many characters are going to be in your word and then generate exactly that many by using `Random.nextInt()` to generate random indices into your alphabet array.

Comment: Im using letters and numbers stored in a char array. it has 36 chars in the array so it loops the array and then adds another char and then loops again and so on. thats my aim but at the moment it always starts with 6 chars.

Comment: also the password it has to guess is between 1 and 6 chars so the word needs to be between 1 and 6.

Comment: This may never finish (depending on whether the PRNG ever generates a number corresponding to the password, which is not at all guaranteed).  Straight iteration, or possibly recursion, over the whole set of passwords is more likely to find a match.  On top of that (ie: even after the random stuff is changed to a `for` loop), this method looks quite inefficient, doesn't account for a password like "QQQQQQA" (leading 0's would be dropped), and won't scale to an alphabet large enough to matter.